# Worksheet Change event in excel only works the first time i Open the workbook. any changes to cell after do not work

Tags: excel, vba

This is just a test of seeing how the change event works.
After I get this working I want to be able to enter a number in one cell in the  Range of C,D, E,F . and have the change trigger automatic entries into the other 3 cells at the same row.
[image: Image of the excel file.]

So far I can't even get the code below to work. It only works once. The first time I put something in c16 it triggers the message but if I change it a second time. No message comes up.  Thank you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False '<--| disable events handling
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler '<--| be sure to catch any error and enable events handling back

Select Case Target.Address

    Case "$C$16"
       'Me.Unprotect
        MsgBox "Test" & Target.Cells.Row

        'Me.Protect


End Select
ErrorHandler:

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn on enable events again

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False '<--| disable events handling
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler '<--| be sure to catch any error and enable events handling back

Select Case Target.Address

    Case "$C$16"
       'Me.Unprotect
        MsgBox "Test" & Target.Cells.Row

        'Me.Protect


End Select

Application.EnableEvents = True
ErrorHandler:

End Sub
```

Comment: Safer to re-enable events *after* `ErrorHandler` - that way your code doesn't crash and leave events turned off

Comment: What does that mean re-enable events. Could you give me an example of the code?  Thank you Tim Williams

Comment: Sorry   see you added something to the code. Thank you.    Thank you Tim Williams